# Is there a way to extrapolate predicted data from lmer

Tags: r, lme4

I am using `lmer` to fit a multilevel polynomial regression model with several fixed effects (including subject-specific variables like age, short-term memory span, etc.) and two sets of random effects (Subject and Subject:Condition). Now I would like to predict data for a hypothetical subject with particular properties (age, short-term memory span, etc.). I fit the model (`m`) and created a new data frame (`pred`) that contains my hypothetical subject, but when I tried `predict(m, pred)` I got an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "mer"
```

I know I could use the brute-force method of extracting fixed effects from my model and multiplying it all out, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9190304/1129973

Comment: the bleeding-edge `lme4Eigen` package (on r-forge, soon (?) to be on CRAN as lme4) has a `predict` method, if you're willing to try it out (you can always compare your answers with `lme4` -- and please let the developers know if they differ!)

Comment: Thanks, the FAQ link was very helpful and I'll try the new `predict` method when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this type of extrapolated prediction easily with the `merTools` package for R: http://www.github.com/jknowles/merTools

`merTools` includes a function called `predictInterval` which provides robust prediction capabilities for `lmer` and `glmer` fits. Specifically, you can use this function to predict extrapolated data, and to obtain prediction intervals that account for the variance in both the fixed and random effects, as well as the residual error of the model.

Here's a quick code example:

```
library(merTools)
m1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1|Subject), data = sleepstudy)
predOut <- predictInterval(m1, newdata = sleepstudy, n.sims = 100)
# extrapolated data
extrapData <- sleepstudy[1:10,]
extrapData$Days <- 20
extrapPred <- predictInterval(m1, newdata = extrapData)
```

Comment: for what it's worth you can get the prediction itself (not the confidence intervals) via `lme4::predict(m1, newdata=extrapData)` (the question above is pretty old), although I do see the value of `predictInterval`.

Comment: Yes, the question is pretty old, and by now `lme4::predict(m1, newdata=extrapData)` works great. Agreed @BenBolker!